# Update record without using subclass of dataModel

Tags: swift3

How can i update record without using subclass  using coredata.
I dont want  method like  people[index].name = newName that is sublass of coreDatamodel .

```
   func updateEntity(index:Int, newName: String){
         let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

          let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
          let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Person")
    do {
        people = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        let dic = ["name":newName]as NSDictionary
        people.remove(at: index)
        people.insert((dic as AnyObject) as! NSManagedObject, at: index)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    appDelegate.saveContext()
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Basically `index` does not work because a fetch without sort descriptor is unordered by default. You can update an attribute of `NSManagedObject` with `setValue:forKey`

Comment: but how can i update  record at specific index!  m new in this . dont know how to  update records

Comment: Entity collections are stored as `Set` which is unordered. What is the criteria for the *Index*?

Comment: Index is like user selected record  index. like if he select 1st record than index is 1.

Comment: Once again, a fetch without sort descriptor returns an unordered array. You need to identify the record by a distinct attribute (for example the record ID).